# Some value to callback function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-callback

So, I have this simple code

```
$('#info_name'+index).show("slide", {direction: "right"}, 1000, function(){
    $('#info_info'+index).show('slide',{direction: "up"}, 1000);
});
```

The `i` is declared upper as just a variable `var i=0`, but in callback, function I can't see it...

Comment: It might help if you posted a larger code snippet.

Comment: show your full code. Where you have declared i, and also post a bit of your html which has an id starting with "info_name"

Comment: If you have `var i = 0;` in the containing scope of the functions above, `i` is definitely accessible within the callback.

Comment: if you run this with a javascript debugger (e.g. Chrome's developer tools), is there an error, and can you confirm that i is definitely `undefined`?

Comment: here is all code, but with delay because i cant figure out how to transfer i to callback

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a scope issue with `i`. Since `i` is declared in the outer scope, all callbacks will reference the same `i`, meaning, if `i` is changed, all callbacks' references to `i` will also be changed.

What you can do is to create a function to generate the callback, since a new scope is created in that case, the value of `i` will be preserved.

Based on the original question, I simplified the code a little bit. You've since edited it, and I can't find the callback anymore... but hope this might help ya

```
var getCallback = function(index) {
    return function(){
        // You can see how this index is being captured correctly in Javascript console
        console.log(index);
        $('#name' + index).show('slide',{direction: "up"}, 1000)
    };
};

for (var i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
    $('#name'+i).show("slide", {direction: "right"}, 1000, getCallback(i));
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vd9Mj/​

UPDATE:

Where's your callback...? It seems you've removed it from the question.

```
var i=-1;

var doStuff = function(index) {
    $('.third').append('<div class="showinfo"><h3 id="info_name'+i+'" class="info_name">'+contact_name[index]+'</h3><span class="info_info" id="info_info'+index+'"><strong>'+contact_information[0][0]+'</strong>: '+contact_number[index]+'</span></div>');
    $('#info_name'+index).show("slide", {direction: "right"}, 1000);
    $('#info_info'+index).delay(1000).show('slide',{direction: "up"}, 1000, function() {
       // Insert code for callback.
    });
};

$.each(contact_status, function(key, value){
    i++;
    if(value == info_id){
        doStuff(i);
    }
});
​
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure this will do what you want, even if `i` was available - if you want your callback function to affect the element the event handler is attached to, use `$(this)`:

```
$('#info_name'+i).show("slide", {direction: "right"}, 1000, function(){
        $(this).show('slide',{direction: "up"}, 1000)
});
```

Comment: no, i need to use i variable, because it has current elements id number. It will appear in other place, with different of different element.